# Laravel Vue Single Page Deployment on Cpanel

Tags: vue.js, deployment, cpanel, laravel-vue

I host my laravel-vue project on Cpanel sub-folder. My welcome page is

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Laravel</title>
        <meta  name="csrf-token" content="{{csrf_token()}}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{asset('css/app.css')}}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{asset('css/animate.css')}}">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="app">
        <app></app>
         </div>
       <script src="{{asset('js/app.js')}}"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

My page gets all sources but the Vue instance isn't rendered. If anyone found the issues. Please help me.

Comment: did you run "npm run prod" ?

Comment: Thanks. It works fine in subdomain and domain. but problem in sub directory.

Comment: @SandipKumar Do you have any js error?